# How to write sa"f"e Active Record queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

I tried to make an API in Rails that could be called dynamically to return min/max/average values for data over various time periods.
I have some scopes like this:

```
  scope :span, ->(span) { group("date_round_down(device_time, '#{span}')::timestamp without time zone") }
  scope :func, ->(func) { calculate("#{func}", 'point_data_val') }
```

But the group method doesn't let me do params and ? substitution like 'where' does.

Is there a safe way to get arguments into the middle of SQL strings in Rails?

Comment: That won't work for `.where` either as the placeholder is escaped so it can't work as a column name. Take `.where('? = 1', 'id')` for example. I would consider using a whitelist instead and using it to construct SQL strings.

Comment: you're choosing a wrong method, the `scope` return an array of values, try a plain method definition.

Comment: Actually scope is just syntactic sugar that declares a class method @Зелёный. You can return whatever you want for example `scope :foo, -> { "bar" }`. Of course doing so would be pretty silly. And its usually used to return a `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

The only "safe" way I can figure out is passing the user input through a whitelist like for example the column names which can be fetched through `.column_names` or a vetted list of acceptable aggregate functions that the user can apply in the query.

Directly interpolating the user input into the query will leave you open to a SQL injection attack and the normal sanitation is not usable for this rather special case as its for binding and sanitizing values - not column names or SQL keywords which would be dangerous and rather stupid from a framework POV.